# How to show a page on install but not on update

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a client that wants the user to be redirected to a page upon installing a Chrome browser extension. I'm using [runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) to do this. However, this has the consequence of showing that page to users whenever the extension is updated as well, which my client doesn't want. Is there a standard/easy way to accomplish this behaviour? Alternatively, if I want to take a more hacky approach, is there any way I can test if what I've done works without having to push a new update to the Chrome web store?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation the listener of the event receives `reason`.

Comment: @wOxxOm ugh my bad -_-